# Img-fluid is not scaling png when used directly inside .col

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm using the code below with Bootstrap 4.1.3 and the my image is not scaling up to the height of the row. Can anyone tell me what I have wrong here.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row top-logo">
        <div class="col text-center"><img src="logo.png" class="img-fluid"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css is:

```
.top-logo {
height: 200px;
}
```

My logo image is a 100x100 png.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not a CSS expert so I am sorry if I cannot give you the best explanation. The **img-fluid** has **height: auto** property behind it but somehow it does not work. However, **height: 100%** does the trick. Bootstrap has **h-100** class to do this. Try adding this to your image class.

`<img src="logo.png" class="img-fluid h-100">`

Answer (score 1):

**.img-fluid** height is **"auto"**. for scale img by height:auto you should set a **width** for img

```css
.top-logo img{
  height: auto;
  width:100%;
  max-width:200px;
}
```

or

```css
.top-logo img{
  height: 100%;
  width:auto;
  /*max-width:200px;*/
}
```